# Linear algebra, semi-positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A\in\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$.Show that $C=A^tA$ is a semi-positive matrix if only if A is a singular matrix.

What I did
$$x^tCx=x^tA^tAx=(Ax)^t(Ax)=||Ax||_2^2\geq0$$

That's right?

I think what you need to prove is:

If C is a positive semi-definite matrix, A is singular then

If A is singular matrix then C is a positive semi-definite matrix

Comment: @Casteels is a singular matrix, that don't have inverse

Comment: In that case, the statement you are trying to prove is false: If $I$ is the identity matrix, then $I=I^TI$ is positive semi-definite, but $I$ is non-singular.

Comment: If $A$ is full column rank, then $C$ is positive definite.

Comment: @Casteels show that is false

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The matrix $A^TA$ is positive semi-definite for all matrices $A$, not just the singular ones.

Comment: @Casteels I edited the question, please take a look

Comment: What I have been trying to say is that it is *not true* that "if $C$ is positive semi-definite, then $A$ is singular." The other part (that if $A$ is singular, then $C$ is positive semi-definite) is true as your proof shows, but the same proof works for non-singular $A$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, $C = AA^T$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: But how to make a proof?

Comment: Your proof is valid for any matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.